# Macbook rearranges windows when monitors are powered off?

Tags: macos

I have a 2017 Macbook Pro running Ventura with 4 external monitors connected.

Every time the I turn my monitors off, the display positions reset, resulting in windows being moved to different monitors.

Also, often upon monitors being turned off, the fan speed increases as soon as I do that, and the cursor becomes a beachball indicating unresponsiveness, lasting for minutes sometiems.  And running "top" I see "kernel_task" has started consuming CPU.

Any ideas on how to correct this?